# CRAttributeList extension with Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

Currently I work with screen ap303000.aspx. I want to add new attribute to tab "Attributes". This tab is binded to view "Answers" which is declared in following way:

```
[PXViewName(CR.Messages.Answers)]
public CRAttributeList<Vendor> Answers;
```

little bit digging with metadata viewer in CRAttributeList shows that CRAttributeList is inherited from PXSelectBase and definitely reads records from CSAnswers table:

```
public class CRAttributeList<TReference> : PXSelectBase<CSAnswers> where TReference : IBqlTable
```

which gives me hint, that I need to insert something into table CSAnswers. Table CSAnswers by it's structure also doesn't give me enough information what should I put in table CSAnswers in order to have some attribute as bool and available to all Vendors and to turn it on by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify list of Attributes at Vendor Class (AP201000) level first.

[image]

Once Vendor class is specified, Attributes specified at Class level will be listed for which value can be assigned.

[image]